# UIlabel() tap to expand text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, mapkit

So I am building a map that provides factual data on a variety of points located in Washington DC. The data is getting pulled from a geojson and listed as 20 or so points. When you click on the point, there is a popup that occurs that shows a truncated version of the text, only 10 lines. However some of the text is really long, 200 lines+. I want to develop a  way to expand the text, or have a scrollable bar. Basically anything to have the option to open up the text. Adding an image to show what it looks like.

You can see an image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeeBa.jpg

Here is the code I am using.

The data is getting called in the ViewController.swift using this

```
    func loadInitialData() {
        // 1
        guard let fileName = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "PublicArt4", ofType: "json")
          else { return }
        let optionalData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileName))

        guard
          let data = optionalData,
          // 2
          let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data),
          // 3
          let dictionary = json as? [String: Any],
          // 4
          let works = dictionary["data"] as? [[Any]]
          else { return }
        // 5
       let validWorks = works.compactMap { Artwork(json: $0) }
        artworks.append(contentsOf: validWorks)
      }

   }
```

The artworkViews.swift displays the label formatting

```
let detailLabel = UILabel()
        detailLabel.text = artwork.locationlink
        detailLabel.text = artwork.subtitle
        detailCalloutAccessoryView = detailLabel
        detailLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Heiti TC", size: 12)
        detailLabel.numberOfLines = 10
        //detailLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        // detailLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        // detailLabel.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
        // detailLabel.textAlignment  = .left
```

The geojson is formatted like this

```
{"data" : [ [
     1,
    "Washington Monument",
    "Click here to learn more",
    "Madison Dr NW & 15th St NW",
    "Washington",
    "DC",
    20001,
    "38.89013",
    "-77.033031",
    "www.google.com Welcome to the Washington Monument,",
    "Mural",
    "Some text, not sure what it is",
    " "
  ],...
```

The Artwork.swift pulls the data in such a way

```
class Artwork: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
let title: String?
let locationName: String
let locationURL: String
let discipline: String
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(title: String, locationName: String, locationURL: String, discipline: String,  coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
  self.title = title
  self.locationName = locationName
  self.locationURL = locationURL
  self.discipline = discipline
  self.coordinate = coordinate
  
    super.init()
  }
    
      
    var subtitle: String? {
      return locationName
    }
    
    var locationlink: String? {
      return locationURL
    }
    
  init?(json: [Any]) {
    // 1
    if let title = json[2] as? String {
      self.title = title
    } else {
      self.title = "No Title"
    }
    // json[11] is the long description
    //self.locationName = json[11] as! String
    // json[12] is the short location string
    self.locationName = json[9] as! String
    self.discipline = json[10] as! String
    self.locationURL = json[3] as! String
    // 2
    if let latitude = Double(json[7] as! String),
      let longitude = Double(json[8] as! String) {
      self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    } else {
      self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    }
  }

    
  // pinTintColor for disciplines: Sculpture, Plaque, Mural, Monument, other
  var markerTintColor: UIColor  {
    switch discipline {
    case "Monument":
      return .red
    case "Mural":
      return .cyan
    case "Plaque":
      return .blue
    case "Sculpture":
      return .purple
    default:
      return .green
    }
  }

  var imageName: String? {
    if discipline == "Mural" { return "Flag" }
    return "Flag"
  }

  // Annotation right callout accessory opens this mapItem in Maps app
  func mapItem() -> MKMapItem {
    let addressDict = [CNPostalAddressStreetKey: subtitle!]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDict)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = title
    return mapItem
  }
}
```

The one thing I tried was to switch it to a UITextView, but i cant get that to load properly. Mainly because I am not sure how to integrate it into the ViewController.

````
         let detailLabel = UITextView()
            detailLabel.text = artwork.locationlink
            detailLabel.text = artwork.subtitle
        detailLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        detailLabel.selectedTextRange = detailLabel.textRange(from: detailLabel.beginningOfDocument, to: detailLabel.beginningOfDocument)
        ```
````

Comment: Is that a map kit MKMapView?

Comment: yes it is! a lot of the  project was taken from this tutorial, then repurposed for my use case. https://www.raywenderlich.com/7738344-mapkit-tutorial-getting-started